# How to disable focus in input required attribute?

Tags: html, angularjs, angular-material

```
<input type="text" ng-model="importContacts.name" required>
```

when I use required attribute auto focus is enable and when it is not use then disable.how to disable focus with required attribute?

Comment: `https://css-tricks.com/almanac/selectors/r/required/ `
and `http://www.wufoo.com/html5/attributes/09-required.html`
this can be help you .take a look.

Comment: use `autofocus="off"`

Comment: @FarzadYZ I already use it.but it's didn't work

Comment: did you try using `tabindex` ? Set the focus on the element u want to have default and set it to `tabindex=1` For the disabled element use `tabindex=2` or 3,4...

Comment: @Iamisti I have use this input field bottom of the page. When the page is display it focus on the input field which is in the bottom of the page. I want to focus the top.